# Anything like tinkerpop for php?

Tags: php, graph-databases, orientdb

I am just getting started with graph databases. I would like to talk to them in a PHP application. In particular, I am looking at [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/orient-db.htm), mainly because of its licensing benefits and features over neo4j.

What is the recommended way to interact with OrientDB within PHP? Is there a generalized framework like tinkerpop for the PHP world?

I would like to query my graphs using mainly gremlin and a bit of OrientDB's extended SQL (only if necessary).

I know there are 2 php connectors: [Orient](https://github.com/congow/Orient) and [OrientDB-PHP](https://github.com/AntonTerekhov/OrientDB-PHP), but have not tried them yet. Has anyone had any experiences with them? What are the pros and cons? I would of course prefer something like tinkerpop for PHP if it exists, but if it doesn't a library geared towards OrientDB is fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Alex, I actually wrote the biggest part of the codebase for Orient (the php library).

In PHP, currently, there is no thing like tinkerpop but I think you should be able to kickstart with Orient. Using it its extremely simple:

```
<?php

namespace Congow\Orient;

use Congow\Orient\Binding\HttpBinding;
use Congow\Orient\Binding\BindingParameters;

require __DIR__.'/../autoload.php';

$parameters = BindingParameters::create('http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:2480/friends');
$binding = new HttpBinding($parameters);

$response = $binding->query('select from friends where any() traverse(0,1) ( @rid = #5:3 ) and @rid <> #5:3');
$friends = $response->getResult();

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    echo $friend->name, "\n";
}
```

Instead of writing the query from scratch you can also use the query builder:

```
$query = new Select(array('myClass'));
$query->orderBy("name ASC", false);

echo $query->getRaw() // SELECT FROM myClass ORDER BY name ASC
```

You could have a look at the tests of the library, or at the mini-samples in the example directory.

We are slowly keep going on with the development, so you find a few resources here: http://odino.org/blog/categories/orientdb/

Cheers,

Comment: Good to hear that development is still active. Does Orient provide anyway to send gremlin queries? I understand that OrientDB's HTTP interface has a gremlin mode (no sql).

Comment: not natively actually

yes, development is active, we usually push stuff weekly as everyone has to deal with his business :)

Answer (score 1):

I know It's been a while but I wanted to point out that you **can** use the Tinkerpop stack in PHP via available drivers.

These will allow you a certain level of abstraction over the underlying database you choose -- thus allowing you to switch DBs when needed (Neo4j, OrientDB, Titan, etc.).

### TinkerPop 3

You can use [Gremlin server](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/#gremlin-server) (new name for rexster) via the php driver available:

- [gremlin-php](https://github.com/PommeVerte/gremlin-php) check this [tutorial](https://dylanmillikin.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/get-up-and-running-with-tinkerpop-3-and-php/)

### Tinkerpop 2 (no longer maintained)

You can use the [Rexster server](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki) from the stack via the php drivers available:

- [rexpro-php](https://github.com/PommeVerte/rexpro-php) check [this](https://dylanmillikin.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/chosing-your-graph-database-for-php/) article
- [Doolittle](https://github.com/ConvergeSystems/Dolittle)
- [rexpro-php-driver](https://github.com/travib/rexpro-php-driver) (PHP ext.)